# What is meant by a "fitness case"?

Tags: genetic-programming

I see this term used often in papers concerning genetic programming but I'm unsure as to its origin and definition. I understand that individuals are scored by a fitness function that determines how good their solution is to the problem but I don't understand how scoring against "fitness cases" works.

I am trying to find a very simple problem that is appropriate for solution using a GP approach and have been working from the first two slides of these notes: http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/nat/slides/nat09h.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fitness case is one of a set of problems against which the performance of a GP can be measured. GP breeding will generally reach a conclusion when a solution is found that scores above some threshold on the fitness cases or when a certain number of time steps has elapsed and no such solution has been found.

Comment: That's fascinating. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Hey, no problem!

Comment: ...are you commenting on your own posts trying to pose as someone else?

Comment: Was it that obvious?